# How many communication antennas does a satellite need if it belongs to a constellation?

Tags: communication-satellite, satellite-constellation

I assume (but I may be wrong) that in a communication satellite constellation such as the one [spaceX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_satellite_constellation) plan to put into service:

- each full duplex link requires a dedicated antenna
- each satellite communicates with a subset of the other satellites in the constellation (some if not all of the sats that are in line of sight)
- a subset of satellites directly communicate with the ground segment
- an active antenna requires a substantial amount of energy to work
- there may be some spare antennas on a satellite

Given all those assumptions, I wonder how many antennas per satellites are required for the constellation to be able to work as expected?

Comment: I'm not sure your assumptions are all correct. You will not need a dedicated antenna per link, and your view of "substantial" may not be correct - they can run very low power antennae.

Comment: @RoryAlsop now I wander how the power needed by an antenna affect its usabale bandwidth (the spaceX constellation is made of communication satellites).

Comment: You may want to read https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin0ouctrLSAhWjIcAKHS5NBswQFggyMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flicensing.fcc.gov%2Fmyibfs%2Fdownload.do%3Fattachment_key%3D1158350&usg=AFQjCNHYcrhJIIEpj0Wjq3V6o4TUUhjXDA&bvm=bv.148073327,d.d2s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are living in the 21st century now. One phased array can support a large number of beams, each pointing in a different direction, each moving at a different rate. All the steering can be done electronically.

So no, you don't need one antenna for every link. Just a few spacecraft-fixed, phased arrays is all that's necessary.

Here is a drawing of an [Iridium Next](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation#Next-generation_constellation) satellite. The SpaceX satellites will look very different, but for the purposes of your question, the Iridium Next is a good enough example.

The large (orange) hexagonal array on its belly is the [L-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_band) (1-2GHz, 30-15cm) is a 48-beam transmit/receive phased array antenna to communicate with multiple ground "customers". Each beam is "generated" in signal processing electronics, and a different phase and possibly (probably) amplitude would be sent to each of the sub-units with the array.

The higher the frequency, the smaller the array can be and still produce tight, steerable beams.

This excellent, detailed [answer about GAIA's phased array](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19864/12102) describes the situation where the spacecraft is spinning around its axis but needs to keep a continuous data lock with Earth. The phased array is designed to handle this and keep a lock over 360 degrees azimuth and 30 to 60 degrees elevation with respect to the spacecraft's mid-plane. It's all done using math and fast processing to generate the correct signal amplitude and phase in each sub-element so that the beam is always optimized.

So the answer is "a few" if you count a single fixed array as an antenna. They are made of many small sub-units, but these are not independent antennas, they are all sharing the same signal.

[image]

**above:** Conceptual drawing of Iridium-NEXT from [Harris](https://www.harris.com/solution/hosted-payload-solutions).

[image]

**above:** Testing the GAIA phased array, from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131213013018/http://utopia.duth.gr/~iaitidis/ESA%20conference%202010/Papers/posters/FCXNL-10C09-2004739-1-2004739garcia.pdf) (paywalled [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5505027/)).

Comment: As for the Iridium NEXT sats, apart from the main mission antenna, they have 4 cross-link antennas for the "neighboring" satellites - one for the sat in front of it and one for the one behind it one the same plane; then one for the next satellite in the eastward and one for the westward plane. Further, they have 2 (?) antennae linking to the ground stations (that's for callers to an Iridium number who do not use an Iridium phone themselves, but e.g. a landline).

Comment: @eerie Thanks! I'd originally tried to include some information like that to the answer but I found the drawing so confusing I could not figure out what is what. Are the four cross-link antennas also phased arrays? It seems they'd have to be steerable somehow. If you'd like, you're welcome to edit the answer and add some information on the cross-link beams, or suggest some place where the cross-link antennas are discussed or at least have an arrow pointing to them so I know what is what. Thanks!

Comment: I unfortunately do not know nor really understand about phased-array. But I read that the in-plane links are fixed, the other ones are steerable. Maybe that helps.
I add an image to the answer with the descriptions inserted. 
A lot of technical information can be found [here](http://spaceflight101.com/spacecraft/iridium-next/)