# Is Starlink VisorSat really dimmer?

Tags: spacex, starlink

Basically a repeat of [Is Starlink 1130 (Darksat) really dimmer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41977/12102) but this time with Visorsat.

What is the observed brightness of VisorSat(s) and is it dimmer than non-Visorsat Starlink satellites?

Comment: different but related (and currently unanswered): [How will SpaceX's VisorSat work? How could a sunshade articulate to shade parts of Starlink satellite as it orbits the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43747/12102)

Comment: also related: [Astrophotographer Thierry Legault is not convinced that DarkSat is darker than the others. Have photometric measurements been reported?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41140/12102) which makes me wonder if Thierry Legault has said anything about VisorSat yet...

Comment: Initial [observation](http://www.satobs.org/seesat/Aug-2020/0044.html]=) of Visorsat in orbit puts max brightness in orbit at magnitude 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initial observations of the [Visorsat](http://www.satobs.org/seesat/Aug-2020/0044.html) put it a mag 7 in final orbit; however larger collections of [observations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.00374) from amateur sat watchers put it at ~mag 6. Since then further [observations](https://spacenews.com/spacex-surpasses-1000-satellite-mark-in-latest-starlink-launch/) by astronomers indicates a mag of 6.5. This represents a 2 mag reduction from Starlink which is ~mag 4.5, however it is still short of mag 7 requirement set by LSST.

And finally an official [graphic](https://licensing.fcc.gov/cgi-bin/ws.exe/prod/ib/forms/reports/related_filing.hts?f_key=-443498&f_number=SATMOD2020041700037) from SpaceX on the Visorsat brightness. Confirmation of 6.5 magnitude average brightness, with it varying below and above that.

[image]

Comment: "Initial observation" suggests a positive identification of the satellite. That's maybe too strong to describe that message which boils down to we didn't see it but should have been able to see objects as faint as magnitude 7.

Comment: I can't `+1` again for all the extra effort. You might consider asking a separate question about the part that seems "Confusing AHAHSAGDH" :-)