# Are Starlink satellites flaring?

Tags: spacex, starlink, visibility-of-spacecraft, iridium, satellite-flare

The "Old and Busted" Iridium satellites flared like crazy because they had big flat metal surfaces for their phased array antennas (that were certainly so shiny completely by accident and never intended to call attention to themselves). the "New Hotness" Iridium satellite antennas are very different and don't have this <s>gimmick</s> characteristic.

- [What is a "Double Iridium Flare" and how close can the two satellites be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14101/12102)
- [What goes into an Iridium Flare prediction model besides the ephemerides?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21184/12102)
- [Why no Iridium-level flares from other satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34855/12102)
- ["old and busted" vs "new hotness" explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha-uagjJQ9k)

The visible Starlink train saga is represented in several questions here and in Astronomy SE so won't cover it here. [Did nobody in the Astronomy community think 12,000 new satellites in LEO might be a problem?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34219/7982)

---

Starlink satellites are giant flat, square metal pancakes with tall, flat-segmented solar panels, and they now have one preferred attitude during their rise from deployment altitude (low, so easy to quickly deorbit the duds) to operational altitude and phasing within a given inclination ring, and a second preferred attitude once operational.

**Question:** Are Starlink satellites flaring? In the same way that the occasional geometry occurred when a near specular reflection of the Sun on to Earth's surface occurs for other satellites, does this happen for Starlinks? Or do the now fairly well established preferred attitudes discussed above pretty much preclude any flaring?

---

---

From [this answer to *Why no Iridium-level flares from other satellites?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34857/12102)

> [image: Iridium flare GIF]  GIF [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Iridium_animation.gif)
>
> #### Old and Busted (original Iridium)
>
> **below** "View of one of the Main Mission Antenna. The hinged base is on the right side." Cropped. From [satobs.org/iridsat.html](http://www.satobs.org/iridsat.html).
>
> [image: old Iridium antenna panel] click for larger
>
> #### New Hotness (Iridium Next)
>
> [image: Iridium Next] click for larger
>
> **above:** Conceptual drawing of Iridium-NEXT from [harris.com/solution/hosted-payload-solutions](https://www.harris.com/solution/hosted-payload-solutions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it appears that Starlinks are/can flare. Here are two videos showing Starlink flares after launch (while still in the train formation):

- [SpaceX Starlink satellite train with flaring, by Movie Vertigo](https://youtu.be/cycLZQtM8HU)
- [StarLink 7 Very Bright Flare, by NG Films](https://youtu.be/viNMYFQXkhc)

These videos are both two and one years old, respectively. The second video begins with a (shaky) zoomed in view that shows (I believe, based on pictures in below linked blog post of the satellites) the antennas causing the flare.

SpaceX's Starlink update blog post [ASTRONOMY DISCUSSION WITH NATIONAL ACADEMY OF SCIENCES](https://www.spacex.com/updates/starlink-update-04-28-2020/index.html) (posted over a year ago) has a very nice write-up on Starlink brightness:

> When sunlight hits a specular surface of the spacecraft and reflects, the vast majority of light reflects in the specular (mirror reflection) direction, which is generally out toward space (not toward Earth). **Occasionally when it does, the glint only lasts for a second or less**. In fact, specular surfaces tend to be the dimmest part of the satellite **unless you are at just the right geometry**. [emphasis mine]

The blog makes no mention of this phenomenon being exclusive to the post-launch/phasing time periods. I could not find any pictures/video of a Starlink flare occurring while in the operational orbit.

Comment: Yep, the newer ones are fainter than the first batches, magnitudes shifted by ~2 I read, but still visible. Also, 3% are unresponsive in orbit (according to a business insider item)

Comment: Perfect Stack Exchange answer! A block quote from an authoritative source that specifically addresses the question, a boolean-like answer (yes) and a couple of supporting videos. *Thanks!*

Comment: Starlink satellite flares can be seen for instance on https://astronomy.com/news/2020/03/nasa-needs-you-to-photograph-starlink-satellites-with-your-smartphone. Smartphones capture them well. A highly efficient CCD on a telescope even more so. The flares are much brighter than nebulous filaments.