# How does China (CASC or CAST) solve Groundsegment?

Tags: spacecraft, china, ground-station

I was studying [Queqiao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4#Queqiao_relay_satellite) space mission and I found a lot about how is Tracking, Telemetry and Command or TT&C solved for space component, but not how is secured Space-Ground connectivity - what type of ground stations (should be S-band), where and so on.

The only thing I have found is the last slide in the following presentation, but not sure about the relevance:

- https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e356cfae72e4563b10cd310/t/5f6e9dbd80f1d5716233beed/1601084864185/CASI+Conference+2020+Wood+Presentation.pdf

Comment: Also, your linked article looks very interesting, and you may be able to write another answer to [What will China's new “space station” in Argentinian Patagonia be used for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29741/12102)

Comment: Oh, this is by CASI: [The mission of Air University's China Aerospace Studies Institute (CASI) is to advance understanding of the capabilities, development, operating concepts, strategy, doctrine, personnel, organization, and limitations of China's aerospace forces.](https://www.airuniversity.af.edu/CASI/)

Comment: My intention for using of shortcuts was that people who know them will most likely answer the question by the way I'm looking for. TT&C stands for Tracking, Telemetry and Comand and stand for the most common applications of radio communication with satellites. GS stands for groundstations. CASC is main Chineese aerospace contractor and CAST is science division of thr organization. Those organization are closely cooperating but not the same.

Comment: Allright, thank you for making my question more approachable!