# Is a 2:1 "figure-eight" Lissajous orbit possible in the Circular Restricted Three Body Problem?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, halo-orbit, lissajous-orbit

[Was Queqiao in a halo or Lissajous orbit? Why do sources disagree?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45920/12102) says

> Proper halo orbits have the same period for their in-plane oscillations and out of plane oscillations, so they are *closed orbits* with roughy circular motion in the rotating frame, whereas Lissajous orbits are those where the two periods are unequal. They could be closed with a period ratio that is a rational number or be *open, non-repeating orbits*. Either way they will have "etch-a-sketch" or "squiggly" Lissajous-like motion. and links to [What is the difference between halo orbits and Lissajous orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31502/12102)

This got me wondering if a 2:1 or "figure eight" Lissajous orbit is possible in the [CR3BP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Restricted_three-body_problem) This would require one period to be *half of the other* which seems pretty extreme to me. If such an orbit is possible, under what constraints is this so? I'm guessing there are limits on $\mu = m_2/(m_1+m_2)$ and the distance between the orbit and the Lagrange point to which it is associated.

Note that the figure eight could be vertical or horizontal.

**Question:** Is a 2:1 "figure-eight" Lissajous orbit possible in the Circular Restricted Three Body Problem?

**note:** this would be in the synodic (rotating) frame of course.

Comment: From that distinction, every planar lissajous orbit is a halo orbit. The planar figure eight orbit is probably the easiest one to find.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys if that's the answer, then *that's the answer!* :-)

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys is it the answer then?