# How do I construct halo orbits around the Sun-Earth L2 point in GMAT? What should the state vector of the spacecraft be?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design, gmat, trajectory-design, state-propagation

I am new to trajectory design, and have been using GMAT to learn it since it's free, unlike STK. I have been trying to design a script that takes a spacecraft from Earth orbit to a halo orbit around Sun-Earth L2, where stationkeeping can then take place to maintain a halo orbit of radius ≈ 100,000 km. A burn simulating the launch vehicle that would do the transfer orbit insertion in real life leads to the spacecraft reaching the desired xyz position, and a second burn (the first in real life) does a breaking maneuver to lower vx, vy and vz such that it can orbit L2.

However, even after looking at the few GMAT sample scripts available involving halo orbits, I do not see any patterns that allow me to understand what the state of the spacecraft should be at the start of the orbit around L2 (i.e., what spacecraft position and velocity I should aim to achieve with the aforementioned burns), other than of course very small, near-zero velocity. Is determining that non-trivial, involving calculations and considerations depending on the epoch the script starts at and the position of the Sun and Earth, or is there some intuitive logic that I am not seeing?

Comment: Starting state vectors for halo orbits have to be found by some combination of numerical simulation and trial-and error, there are no simple rules, neither of thumb nor intuition that I know of. Search terms "shooting method" and "state transition matrix". See also the many excellent answers to [How to best think of the State Transition Matrix, and how to use it to find periodic Halo orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20590/12102) and Kathleen Howell's 1984 paper.

Comment: @uhoh thank you, now I know where to start.

Comment: I don't want to scare you, but if you do start "hunting for halo orbits" there are a surprisingly large number of closed, periodic orbits possible. See [this answer to *What sort of orbital elements are used to describe halo orbits?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27603/12102) which links to [Elemental periodic orbits associated with the libration points in the circular restricted 3-body problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263880073_Elemental_periodic_orbits_associated_with_the_libration_points_in_the_circular_restricted_3-body_problem)