# Google maps for Space exploration

Tags: mars, the-moon, mapping

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://maps.google.com/maps/%4037.0625,-95.677068,2z&ved=2ahUKEwjNtc2B3cP9AhVn8jgGHWCNDBsQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0kz0f3l6f6m2n5yUKro8N5)

Can Google Maps for Space Exploration be defined similar to our planet Earth? I.e Planet Mars exploration, Moon exploration, International Space Station (ISS) journey and other planets of the Solar System.

I.e Plotting Maps for visiting Mars, Moon, ISS & other Planets of the Solar System.

Map will show Manned and UnManned Crew Spaceship / SpaceShuttle, Distance, Route, Space points, Shortest distance available to reach the destination from Planet Earth.

If Yes, Are they publicly accessible on the  "World Wide Web"?

If Not, Will this be considered as a Science Fiction Novel to be written for the Topic "Google Maps for Space exploration"?

Comment: Better sounds `OpenStreetMap of Space`.

Comment: OpenSpaceMap...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> [...] Distance, Route, Space points, Shortest distance available to reach the destination from Planet Earth.

For this purpose, space maps tend to be more abstract. If they weren't, solar system maps would be mostly solid black with solar system objects as single pixels.

One such kind abstract map is **delta-v maps**. They show how expensive it is to get from one location to another using rocket power. "how expensive" here means how much the spacecraft must change its own velocity, which is [what rockets use their fuel for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

Space maps are all about numbers. Sometimes there are only numbers.

*How to use: add up the numbers along the path from origin to destination. If a segment has an arrow, you can go in the direction of the arrow for free by braking in an atmosphere*

[image: delta-v map]

Comment: By *braking* in the atmosphere. *Breaking* in the atmosphere is not recommended. :D

Comment: @Cadence It’s still probably preferable to braking in the ground.

Comment: some more interesting libration point orbit classification "maps" at the bottom of [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27603/12102)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn lithobraking is a very good way to break things

Answer (score 18):

[Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/versions/) already includes the Moon and Mars.

[image]

[image]

I don't think it covers traveling there though.

Comment: There is also a web version for the moon: https://www.google.com/moon/ Back in the days, when zooming in, on the most refined level it showed some comic cheese. Not any more. Mars has also a web version: https://www.google.com/mars/

Comment: (More on that Swiss cheese thing for those who hazily recollected it like me or interested in the history... I thought I remembered it being an April Fools Day thing, but apparently not: [initial release](https://www.eastbaytimes.com/2005/07/25/google-finds-cheese-on-moon/) and then [swiss cheese removal](https://www.universetoday.com/11796/google-moon-gets-a-big-update))

Comment: We probably all take this sort of thing for granted, but holy hell is it impressive that we have access to this kind of information.