# Satellites that take advantage of, or require constant availability of sunlight on the spacecraft itself, available in Sun-synchronous orbits?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, sun-synchronous

**[ditto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark):** "Are there satellites that take advantage of, or require constant availability of **sunlight on the spacecraft itself**, available in [Sun-synchronous orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit)?"

This question is an offshoot of [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32192/12102).

---

As a clarifying **example** of what "take advantage of... availability of sunlight" means [as requested](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32193/satellites-that-take-advantage-of-or-require-constant-availability-of-sunlight?noredirect=1#comment98163_32193) in comments, a satellite could, potentially, substantially reduce the volume and mass of its battery if it could take advantage of the constant availability of sunlight in a Sun-synchronous orbit. Depending on specifics, it might still require a small battery for backup of critical low-level functions. That's just a hypothetical example for clarification purposes.

A clarifying **counterexample** would be a satellite that takes advantage of the constant availability sunlight **reaching the Earth's surface** so that it can be photographed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two classical examples of spacecraft which "take advantage" of being (almost) constantly insolated:

**1- Sun Observation Missions:**

Spacecraft in Lagrange's points such as [SOHO](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/soho) or in dawn-dusk orbit such as [PROBA-2](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/p/proba-2) want to look at the sun, because that is what their payloads were made for. No eclipse time means no interruption of the data flow.

**2- Synthetic Aperture Radars**

SAR antennas require a really high peak power. Because of that, some satellites such as [TerraSAR-X](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/content/-/article/terrasar-x) or [RADARSAT-2](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/content/-/article/radarsat2) also operate in dawn-dusk
 orbit and can only turn on the payload when it's possible to drain power form both the solar arrays and the battery simultaneously.

Comment: I think this answer is as complete as it can get, and yet concise, and with supporting links as well. Perfect!

Comment: "...take advantage of near-constant insolation" sounds so-so, but [insolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_insolation) is really what *makes it all the way to the surface of the Earth*. For space, the better word is [solar irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance) if a word is needed.