# Can/Will the James Webb Telescope maintain its position passively?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, james-webb-telescope

A [recent article](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/james-webb-gold-mirror-style/index.html) about the telescope states (emphasis mine):

> Unlike Hubble, which orbits the Earth at about 340 miles of altitude,
>   Webb will be sent almost a million miles into space, at a specific
>   location called "L2." It's one of five so-called Lagrange points,
>   specific areas of stability where the gravity from the Earth and the
>   Sun balances out in such a way that putting an object there keeps it
>   in a fixed position relative to the two celestial bodies. **The
>   telescope will therefore hitch a ride through space without the need
>   for engines or propulsion**, while enjoying an unobstructed view.

The same article also notes:

> To protect itself from the warmth of the Sun, **the mirror will sit on a
>   70-ft sunshield** -- as long as a tennis court -- made of a special
>   heat-resistant material. **It looks like a giant kite** and it will keep
>   the mirror at a gelid -370°F, or -223°C, nearly three times colder
>   than the coldest temperature ever recorded on Earth.

From which I gather that the telescope is designed to sit at the L2 Lagrange point while using minimal (if any) propulsion to maintain its position and orientation.  However the second paragraph makes it sound like the telescope will sport what essentially sounds like a (quite small) solar sail.

So the question is, if the 'sunshield' is always positioned between the telescope and the sun and therefore always being irradiated by the sun, won't that over time generate enough thrust the push the telescope out of position or alignment, particularly if it's a truly passive system and not able to counteract with its own engines/maneuvering thrusters?

Comment: It looks like CNN's style writers need to do a better job of consulting CNN's science writers (if they have any). That article, while very stylish (the article is in CNN Style, not CNN Space) has some glaring errors. You've picked out two, hitching a ride without the need for engines or propulsion, and "three times colder than the coldest temperature ever recorded on Earth."

Comment: Well I did try the Fox News version.  They ignored the story completely and were instead blaming the FBI for the telescope's launch delay, saying they used it to illegally spy on the upper floors of Trump Tower during the 2016 election.  :)

Comment: @aroth please tell me that about Fox _is_ a joke... it is, right? It's sad how ridiculous you can go without making that obvious.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, it is.  Hence the `:)`.  One must always be careful to mark absurd claims about Fox News as jests, because you never know when one might turn out to be true.

Comment: It has thrusters. There's an answered question on this site about that. Don't know how to link to it in the mobile app though :(

Comment: @DavidHammen I'd say three - calling a Lagrange point, generally, an "area of stability" is [not really correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_orbit), especially in the case of L2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No it will not**

According to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/284/why-should-the-james-webb-space-telescope-stay-in-the-unstable-l2), James Webb will require 150 m/s of $\Delta v$ to maintain its orbit for its mission duration (5 year), an overall very small amount
See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286642/why-are-the-lagrangian-points-l-1-l-2-l-3-unstable) as to why L2 isn't perfectly stable.

**It looks like a giant kite**

- This is purely a cosmetic remark, and the heat shield is absolutely not designed to produce any  thrust
- Most $\Delta v$ will be spent counteracting gravitational effects and not light pressure (although we can expect a paper quantifying the solar pressure on James Webb :)).

### Doing the maths

**Facts**

- The solar pressure at L2 is [$4.533\times10^{-6}\text{N}/\text{m}^2$](https://bhi.gsfc.nasa.gov/documents/Mission_Concept_Work/ISAL_January_2002_SST/SST_ISAL-1/Super_Star_Tracker/L2-natural-environment.pdf)
- James Webb is about 6000kg
- The shade is $300 \text{m}^2$.
- The pressure exerted on JW is $300 \times 4.533\times10^{-6}\text{N}$ <=> $0.001\text{N}$
- Using a [calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/acceleration) it gives 5m/s per year of acceleration.

Comment: The spacecraft will not be partially shadowed by the Earth (it orbits hundreds of thousands of kilometers about L2), and the heat shield will produce the equivalent of thrust. Solar radiation pressure is small but accumulative, and is a major concern for spacecraft in geosynchronous orbits -- and for spacecraft in pseudo-orbits about one of the unstable Lagrange points.

Comment: "the heat shield is absolutely not designed to produce any thrust" I get that this is true, however not being _designed_ to produce thrust doesn't (necessarily) mean that it won't.  And the rest of the answer seems to imply that it will produce thrust (albeit only a tiny amount)?

Comment: @DavidHammen earth is in the middle. It's not a full eclipse (else the solar panels wouldn't work, but the light is definitely dimmed by earth. Maybe I should use a better technical term ? Shadow != dark so I think it's ok. I'll edit informations about the solar pressure.

Comment: More specific information about JWST's halo orbit in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23249/12102). Also, the question [Can the James Webb Space Telescope basically manage its own orbit if necessary?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18504/12102) has some relevant information.

Comment: Also, according to my answer there, which cites Wikipedia, the JWST will likely consume only 2 to 4 m/s of delta-v per year for station keeping. This sounds quite low, but it's because of the aggressive 3-week updates to the orbit. 150 m/s is the total budget and includes a mid-course correction *on the way to L2*.

Comment: @uhoh Oh, that's interesting; I might have made a mistake in my calculations or maybe the sun pressure will actually help maintaining an appropriate orbit ? I'll double check that later.

Comment: @Antzi the moon orbits the Earth, so solar pressure is towards the Moon for two weeks then away from the moon for two weeks, so the net effect may be quite small.

Comment: @Antzi - That would be the case if the Webb was **at** the Sun-Earth L2 point. From 1.5 million km, the Earth appears to be slightly smaller than does the Sun. The Earth would eclipse a large portion of the Sun at the Sun-Earth L2 point. However, the Webb will never be **at** the Sun-Earth L2 point. It instead will be in a rather wide pseudo orbit about that point, with the pseudo orbit specifically designed so that neither the Earth nor the Moon ever eclipses even a small part of the Sun throughout the ten year projected lifetime of the Webb.

Comment: @DavidHammen I understand now. Edited my answer thank you for your clarifications

Comment: Light pressure: 1) due to the Halo Orbit, the angle between JWST, the Sun and Earth will be 25-37 degrees, so no ways is the Earth's 0.5 degree penumbra shadow cone touching it.  2) Light pressure is almost insignificant for orbit maintenance, as it is almost all tangential to the orbit. But it *is* an issue for attitude control, hence the aft flap, to reduce the thruster workload for reaction wheel desaturation.